# Doing an idempotent insert with postrgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like something like

```
INSERT VALUES(1,2,3) INTO sometable ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING IF EXACTLY SAME ROW
```

So I'd like The following behavior:

```
#CREATE TABLE sometable (a int primary key, b int, c int);

CREATE TABLE
 #INSERT INTO sometable (1,2,3) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING IF EXACTLY SAME ROW
INSERT 0 1
 #INSERT INTO sometable (1,2,3) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING IF EXACTLY SAME ROW
INSERT 0 0
 #INSERT INTO sometable (1,3,2) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING IF EXACTLY SAME ROW
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sometable_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (a)=(1) already exists.
```

Desiring this seems a very natural thing, because a client application can't assume it will know if an insert succeeded (if postgres or the client crashes or the network fails, the request might have been processed but the client never receives confirmation). So any well written application needs to deal with this case somehow.

However, the least bad way of achieving this that I have found is still very annoying:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3) ON CONFLICT(a) UPDATE set sometable.b=2 WHERE sometable.b=2 AND sometable.c=3;
```

In other words, do a no-op update, but only if the values are what you would have inserted and then throw an error if 0 rows (rather than 1) where touched.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an INSERT based on a select:

```
insert into sometable
select *
from ( values (1,2,3) ) as data(a,b,c)
where not exists (select *
                  from sometable
                  where data = sometable);
```

Yes, the condition `where data = sometable` is valid in Postgres and simply compares all columns.

This can also be extended to multiple rows:

```
insert into sometable
select *
from ( 
  values 
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9)
) as data(a,b,c)
where not exists (select *
                  from sometable
                  where data = sometable);
```

This does not prevent PK violation errors (as `on conflict` does) if done from multiple transactions though. You still need to handle those errors.

Comment: You can add `ON CONFLICT` to your query as well.

Comment: @klin: good point, that would prevent the unique key violation

Comment: This is nicer than my solution because it reduces the boilerplate a little bit, and will blow automatically when one tries to insert some data where with the same primary key, but different other columns. Does it behave the same in all other respects?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name probably to be idempotent also in the case of NULLs one needs `WHERE data IS NOT DISTINCT FROM sometable)`? 
Also, where is the neat all-column-comparison syntax described? Is it an implicit row constructor comparison?