# Idempotent INSERT, raise error if values are new

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out a single query that can perform idempotent inserts, but raise an error when duplicate inserts do not contain the same information.

For example, given an existing table:

```
| name   | email                |
|--------|----------------------|
| joseph | joseph@somewhere.com |
| frank  | frank@somewhere.com  |
```

Where `email` has a `UNIQUE` constraint.
Inserting `('joseph, 'joseph@somewhere.com')` should do nothing (which I have achieved),
But inserting  `('francis', 'frank@somewhere.com')` should raise an error from the unique constraint violation, because the "name" value is new.

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Full example:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  email VARCHAR UNIQUE,
  name VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO "users" (name, email) VALUES
  ('joseph', 'joseph@somewhere.com'),
  ('frank', 'frank@somewhere.com');

INSERT INTO "users" (name, email) VALUES
  ('joseph', 'joseph@somewhere.com'), -- Same values, should do nothing
  ('frankie', 'frank@somewhere.com')  -- New "name" value, should raise error
  ON CONFLICT (email)
    DO NOTHING
```

This SQL will successfully run - [here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f31aa/1) - but I want it to raise an error from the second set of values.

This is a similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452603/doing-an-idempotent-insert-with-postrgres), but I'm not able to get that solution to raise the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add another unique constraint {unique(email,name)} to your table so it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  email VARCHAR UNIQUE,
  name VARCHAR,
  unique(email,name)
);
```

And then change your query to:

```
INSERT INTO "users" (name, email) VALUES
  ('joseph', 'joseph@somewhere.com'), -- Same values, should do nothing
  ('frankie', 'frank@somewhere.com')  -- New "name" value, should raise error
  ON CONFLICT (email,name)
    DO NOTHING
```

then it works. You want the unique constraint for email to be shown as an error, but the unique constraint for email and name in combination to fail silently.

Maybe there is a more elegant solution to this, but it is close to the solution you already have.

This does not raise an error if the name is the same and the email is different, as the name does not have a unique constraint.